# Why does this work in JS and not PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, array-splice

Did a project in coding school a while back in JS where we were using the **Sieve of Eratosthenes** (I can't not read in that in some kind of booming, echoey voice) to output all the prime numbers up to a user inputted number.  The code we came up with for that is:

## JavaScript Code Example

```
var primeSifter = function(number) {
  var numArray = numberList(number);
  var prime = 2;
  var count = 0;
  while (prime <= number) {
    numArray.forEach(function(num) {
      if ((num !== prime) && (num % prime === 0)) {
        numArray.splice(numArray.indexOf(num), 1);
      }
    });
    count++;
    prime = numArray[count];
  }
  return numArray;
}
```

*numberList()* is just a function that creates an array of numbers from 2 to whatever number the user inputs.

```
count++;
prime = numArray[count];
```

The idea here was to skip looking for multiples of numbers that were already removed by setting prime equal to the next index position of `numArray`, which should be the next largest prime number. **This is what I'd like to figure out how to implement in PHP.**  I can confirm that this works.  In PHP however...

## PHP Code Examples

**In the original, unedited post, I had used `unset` instead of `array_splice`.  Per A Sad Dude's answer I started playing around with both of them.**

This code gives the errors shown below regardless of whether I `unset` or `array_splice`.

```
function number_list($input) {
  $numList = array();
  for ($i = 2; $i <= $input; $i++) {
    array_push($numList, $i);
  }
  return $numList;
}

function sift_primes($input) {
  $numArray = number_list($input);
  $prime = 2;
  $count = 0;
  while ($prime <= $input) {
    foreach ($numArray as $key => $num) {
      if (($num !== $prime) && ($num % $prime === 0)) {
        array_splice($numArray, $key, 1);
      }
    }
    $count++;
    $prime = $numArray[$count];
  }
  return $numArray;
}
```

**This is what I originally came here to figure out: how are these two functions fundamentally different in JS and PHP?**

---

**The following is sort of an extension of the original question:**

The only way I found to get this function to return a valid output is by replacing:

```
$count++;
$prime = $numArray[$count];
```

With:

```
$prime++;
```

However even when it gives me an output, `unset` and `array_splice` give me different results.

This code outputs `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 [3] => 9 )`, which is not correct, as 9 is obviously not a prime number:

```
function sift_primes($input) {
  $numArray = number_list($input);
  $prime = 2;
  $count = 0;
  while ($prime <= $input) {
    foreach ($numArray as $key => $num) {
      if (($num !== $prime) && ($num % $prime === 0)) {
        array_splice($numArray, $key, 1);
      }
    }
    $prime++;
  }
  return $numArray;
}
```

Replacing `array_splice` with `unset($numArray[$key])` returns:
`Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [3] => 5 [5] => 7 )`, the correct answer.

## Main question:

**The question is NOT "How do I get the output I want?"  I believe I've already figured out how to make that happen.  I'm really trying to understand what's happening behind the scenes in both languages to make a valid approach in JS (first code block above) an invalid one in PHP (specifically, why can't I set `$prime` to be the next prime number in the array after splicing non-primes out?).  It seems like they handle splices differently on a fundamental level (and apparently PHP even handles `unset` and `array_splice` differently as well, which maybe is an extension of the first question), which seems like a really valuable thing to understand.**

## Error Messages

**These are referenced above**

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Users/Guest/Desktop/test/sift.php on
>   line 23
>
> Warning: Division by zero in /Users/Guest/Desktop/test/sift.php on
>   line 18
>
> Warning: Division by zero in /Users/Guest/Desktop/test/sift.php on
>   line 18
>
> Warning: Division by zero in /Users/Guest/Desktop/test/sift.php on
>   line 18
>
> Warning: Division by zero in /Users/Guest/Desktop/test/sift.php on
>   line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /Users/Guest/Desktop/test/sift.php on
>   line 23
>
> Warning: Division by zero in /Users/Guest/Desktop/test/sift.php on
>   line 18

And on and on and on...

## Edit

**I went ahead and did a bit of rearranging/formatting to try and better articulate the issue.  It was mostly in response to the reply by "a sad dude," in which he suggested using `array_splice` instead of `unset`.  The reasoning seemed to make total sense, but I discovered that it didn't quite seem to have the anticipated result.**

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to wade through this.  First time trying to get an answer on here, my apologies if I'm making it more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: JS does support division by zero, PHP not :). So PHP does not like 8 / 0. You should check your variables value before doing operations, in PHP. The only operation I see is *$num % $prime*. So check $prime and $num.

Comment: Somehow $prime is getting 0 as its value.  I would check your number_list function.

Comment: I included the number_list function above.  If there is an undefined offset, then would it make sense that $prime is getting assigned to "NULL" or "undefined", which would be the same as trying to divide by 0?  

I guess I just don't know how array_splice, or Array.splice( ) works differently between the two languages.  In JS it seems like when it splices the array, it just reassigns the keys to the appropriate values, so numArray[2] = 3 the first time around and then numArray[2] = 5 after the first loop.  Question mark?

Answer (score 1):

`unset($a[idx])` is more like `a[idx] = undefined` than `splice`.

You can check yourself:

```
$a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
unset($a[1]);
print_r($a);
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 0
  [2] => 2
  [3] => 3
)
```

So that by taking `$prime = $numArray[$count];` you will hit those blank spots which will be converted to `0` for the division operation. You should either, indeed, use `array_splice`, or reorganize your code.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have fixed changed it to array_splice($numArray, $key, 1);

Unfortunately it doesn't help with the larger issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you still get div by zero errors? Could you post updated code?

Comment: My apologies, still kinda new.  About to wrap up four months at a code school here in Portland.  I see what you're saying about those blank spots.  It looks like we're dealing with a couple of variables here.  

First: whether I do `$count++` and `$prime = $numArray[$count];` OR simply `$prime++`.  Only the latter returns a valid output (i.e. an array), regardless of whether I `unset` or `array_splice`.    

Second: when I do get an actual output, (using `$prime++`), `array_splice` gives me 2, 3, 5, 9 (wrong), whereas `unset` gives me 2, 3, 5, 7 (correct).  Posting full code in a sec.